# Nextjs serving the same content for all routes

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, docker, next.js, dockerfile

I’ve deployed a Nextjs app using docker to AWS infrastructure. The index page (/) loads fine, however, the content of index is loaded for every other route including the api routes as well as the js and css resources.

I’ve attempted running the app with just `next start` as well as building a standalone version and running `node server.js`. Both ways result in the same thing.

Dockefile looks like this

```
FROM node


ARG VERSION
ENV VERSION=${VERSION}

ARG COMMIT_REF
ENV COMMIT_REF=${COMMIT_REF}

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apt/lists

COPY src ./src
COPY node_modules ./node_modules
COPY package.json ./
COPY next.config.js ./
COPY next-env.d.ts ./
COPY babel.config.js ./
COPY tsconfig.eslint.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY types.d.ts ./
COPY public ./public

RUN npx next build

ADD ./docker/start.sh /start.sh

RUN chmod +x /*.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but,
we have a web app in react and we did have this problem also.
The problem you are facing probably isn’t in your Dockerfile but in your build/config file.

We've fixed the issue by adding `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to the build tag script in package.json eg.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

And then we ran a `npm run build` command.

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP is using a Next.js app, not CRA.